# How to access a String that is in JSON array format

Tags: jquery, json

I have an asp.net page which is returning a list of object as a json string to an ajax request. The string is as follows :

```
[
    {"Name":"Don","Age":23,"Description":"Tall man with no glasses"}
    ,{"Name":"Charlie","Age":24,"Description":"Short man with glasses"}
]
```

I want to access each field individually, like the name of the person, his age, his description etc.

How can I do that? I am using JQuery for client-side scripting.

For further clarification, here is the server-side C# code -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request["field1"] != null)
    {            
        createPersonList();
    }
}

private void createPersonList()
{
    List<Person> PersonList = new List<Person>();

    Person Atiq = new Person("Atiq Hasan Mollah", 23, "Whassap Homie");
    Person Sajib = new Person("Sajib Mamud", 24, "Chol kheye ashi");

    PersonList.Add(Atiq);
    PersonList.Add(Sajib);

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PersonList);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(json);
    Response.End();
}
```

The client-side javascript code is as follows -

```
$(function()
{   
    $("#SimpleButton").click(function()
    {

        $.post("Default.aspx", {field1: $("#field1").val()},function(data)
        {
            data = $.trim(data);
            $("#field2").val(data);

            var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');

            $(data).each(function(index, person)
            {
                alert(  'Name: ' + person.Name + 
                        ' Age: ' + person.Age + 
                        ' Description: ' + person.Description
                    );
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Now if I don't use "eval" myself, then how can I pass the arraylist from server-side and then parse it using javascript ?

Comment: I would recommend you to avoid calling the `eval` method yourself. If you perform your AJAX query with jQuery it will handle the conversion of the server response which represents a JSON encoded object to the object itself.

Comment: I tried not to use "eval" by myself. Instead I tried to use "$.getJSON" method of the jquery. But when the server returns the JSON encoded string, then if I try to access it, then it is generating some error. I am giving the server side code as well as the whole client-side code for further clarification.

Comment: If you want to use `$.post` and still have jQuery parse the JSON automatically, you can tell it via the fourth parameter: `$.post("Default.aspx", {field1: $("#field1").val()}, function(data) { ... }, "json");`. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask jQuery to parse the JSON automatically and return a JavaScript object rather than a string:

```
var people = $.getJSON('http://example.com/path/to/page');
```

If you want to use `POST` rather than `GET`, you can provide a data type as the fourth parameter:

```
$.post("Default.aspx", {field1: $("#field1").val()}, function(data) { ... }, "json");
```

You can then access it just as you would a normal object:

```
$.each(people, function(function (i, person) {
    $('#people').append($('<p>').text(person.Name));
}
```

Comment: This is the way I usually do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the persons array you could use the [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method to loop through the elements:

```
var persons = [
    {"Name":"Don","Age":23,"Description":"Tall man with no glasses"},
    {"Name":"Charlie","Age":24,"Description":"Short man with glasses"}
];

$(persons).each(function(index, person) {
    alert('Name: ' + person.Name + 
          ' Age: ' + person.Age + 
          ' Description: ' + person.Description
    );
});
```

Comment: Well, I just needed the first part, actually, I mean how to convert a string into an actual array, but I managed it by my own. But your answer has taught me a new thing that I didn't know before: accessing a list like that using jquery. Thanks....... :)